# MySQL primary key auto increment reset issue

Tags: mysql

I have a primary key with auto increment column in a table. Last week the number was 48. Today for some reason it's generating from the beginning started at 1. What could be the issue? Is this an issue with the new year change? Please let me know. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` value needs an `ALTER TABLE` statement to reset. Did you dump and re-import the table?

Comment: I am not using an commands to re-import the table. I am deleting the data every 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto_increments are not tied to dates in any way, unless you've done something to do so. They're just a number field that increments each time a new record is inserted. The only way to reset an auto increment is to drop/readd the field, or do an `alter table yourtable set auto_increment=new_value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MySql query browser, just right click on your table, click on the edit table option, choose the *advanced option* tab and check the auto increment value. You can directly change your desired value there as shown in the following snap shot (Third field from the beginning).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you delete that table with `TRUNCATE TABLE` command ? That drops and recreate the table, so it resets auto increment column to 1